# I want to have a dropdown menu where you choose the number instead of the variable

Tags: javascript, html

the "var aantal = 10" gives me 10 traingles but I would like the user to insert their own amount of triangles.

```
      var aantal = 10;   
      var triangle = [];

      for (var i = 0; i < aantal; i++){
          triangle[i] = new Triangle;
          triangle[i].xLeft = 20 + 30*i;
          triangle[i].yLeft = 20 + 20*i;

      }
```

Comment: then you have to ask him for the amount of triangles he wants, and use this number in your code. #function #argument

Answer (score 0):

A quick and easy way to ask for user input in a browser is via the [`Window.prompt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt) method.

This stops your code until the user presses "OK" or "Cancel" in a popup window. When the user fills in a value and presses "OK", the value is returned as a `string`. Here's an example:

```js
var userInput = prompt("How many triangles do you want?", 10);
var count = parseInt(userInput, 10);

for (var i = 0; i < count; i += 1) {
  console.log("Triangle " + i);
}
```

Note that you need to explicitly convert the `string` to a `number`. Additionally, you might want to check for `null` or `NaN`: when a user presses "Cancel" or fills in invalid data, you'll need to have a fallback.

Once this works, you might want to try to create an `<input type="number">` HTML element and get your data from there.

Answer (score 0):

I think Bas is asking for a html drop down list that triggers a function, something like this:

```html
<!-- /JavaScript code-->
<script>
  function setTriangles(value) {
    var aantal = eval(value);//evaluate the input as it's coming as a string
    if (aantal == 0) { //do nothing if the user has picked the description "Select number of triangles" in the drop down
      return;
    }
    var triangle = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < aantal; i++) {
      triangle[i] = new Triangle;
      triangle[i].xLeft = 20 + 30 * i;
      triangle[i].yLeft = 20 + 20 * i;
    }

  }
</script>
<!-- /end of JavaScript code-->

<!-- /HTML code-->
<select id="input" onChange="setTriangles(this.value);">
  <option value="0">Select number of triangles</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
  <option value="20">20</option>
  <option value="30">30</option>
</select>

<!-- /end of HTML code-->
```